# How to make the submenu on the same row as the parent link?

Tags: drupal

I am working on a project in Drupal, and I am in charge of the menus. My project manager wanted the submenus to be on the same row as the parent link? Is there anyway I can do this?

http://www.muredhawks.com/  (we wanted the menus like the one on this website

Answer (score 0):

Even if I don't understand clearly your question, to achieve the result of the website you linked, you can try the [Superfish](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish) module or the [MegaMenu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu) module.